# Add loader while workbook is freeze

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I have this code inside workbook_open:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    FormLoad.show
  Stuff....
    Unload FormLoad
    FormInserimentoDati.show

  End Sub
```

before FormLoad is open it takes 5 seconds, how can I add a loader untile the form is shown?
Thanks!

Comment: What is a "Loader"?

Comment: @JNevill a indicator, like a loading bar...

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are you trying to make a progress bar appear on the userform that is taking some time to initialize. You can easily find tutorials on how to make a progress bar using inside a userform (e.g. [this one](https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/beautiful-vba-progress-bar-with-step-by-step-instructions/)), but if you get stuck don't hesitate to ask a specific question about that issue.

Comment: @DecimalTurn Thanks for your answer but I'm not trying to show a progress bar but I want to display something in tose 5 seconds of gap between the opening of the workbook and the form

Comment: The write some code to show something and then some code to remove that something after the loading is done. If you get stuck, please head on out here to Stackoverflow to ask about it. Otherwise this is too broad. Just keep in mind that VBA is a single threaded language so there won't be any code running *during* the time that it takes your computer to run this slow line of code.